# How to automatically download packages from CTAN with WinEdt

Tags: winedt, miktex2.9

I've been working with Miktex2.9/WinEdt10 for at least 2-3 years without issue.
Yesterday, I tried (and failed) to make latexdiff work.
In the process, I reinstalled Miktex.
Now, if I compile anything with WinEdt, all the packages must be reinstalled.
This process before was automatic, whenever a new package was required, a box would pop up (See the image attached) and I simply had to press 'Install' to download the package from wherever.
Now, the same thing happens, but if I click 'Install' (for example, it asks me to install natbib), it will say : LaTeX Error: File 'natbib.sty' not found.
I've tried changing the mirror, but it doesn't work.

Literally, nothing changed, but somehow the packages don't download automatically.
How do I fix this ?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Open MiKTeX console, and  click on the `Settings, General`  tab. It is where you can set the parameters for installation on the fly of missing packages.

Comment: It doesn't work.
In the log file, it says that the repository is outdated.
I've never seen this error.

Comment: You may choose your preferred repository. Just  install any package you need from the console, and install it to check it works, then select this repository for installation on the fly.

Comment: I tried multiple repositories, they just don't work.
If I select "random repository on the internet" or something, it got passed natbib, but now is stuck on url.sty and caption.sty.
I don't understand why the computer can't find the appropriate repositiories

Comment: B.t.w. are you in France? `distrib-coffee.ipsl.jussieu.fr` works fine for me.

Comment: No, in California

Comment: Another possibility wouldbe to make a repository on your own computer. You don't have to download all packages: only those you're interested in, and  the 5 necessary files to use the database: pr.ini, files.csv.lzma, miktex-zzdbi-2.9.tar.lzma` (xhere i=1,2,3) with a download manager such as `filezilla`.

Comment: I tried to download the packages one by one, but it was never ending

Comment: Strange… Even from CTAN?

Comment: yes, it works if i download on CTAN and put them in the Miktex folder
but then I would need to do this for a million packages, so it's not practical

Comment: Don't you have an ftp download manager?

Comment: no idea what this is.
I use WinEdt

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120296/discussion-between-bernard-and-frederic-ouimet).