# Is automatic download in WinEdt still a problem?

Tags: winedt, miktex-update

This question never got an answer  [how-to-automatically-download-packages-from-ctan-with-winedt](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/585449/how-to-automatically-download-packages-from-ctan-with-winedt).  The discussion trailed off in comments and chat with never a solution.  And now I have the same problem.

I have used on-the-fly download for MiKTeX in WinEdt for years.  My MikTeX is still confugured that way:

[image: MiKTeX set to install packages on the fly]

But it does not happen.  I have to install each needed package, one at a time, and it is a terrible lot of work.

How can I recover on-the-fly downloads?

Comment: No idea, (it works fine for me), perhaps you have some virus protection which blocks miktex. Why don't you install simply everything in one go?

Comment: The packages are not blocked.  They install just fine, one at a time.  I would install everything but as far as I can find, basic-miktex-24.1-x64.exe is the only installer MiKTeX currently offers.  The Admin console says there is a way to upgrade to a standard installation, but the link leads to a 404 error "No webpage was found for the web address: https://miktex.org/howto/upgrade".

Comment: On-the-fly installation needs other permissions than a manual installation especially if you have no ask-me first dialog and want to install for all users.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer  Thanks.  The page https://miktex.org/howto/miktex-console discusses automatic package installation but says nothing about permissions.  Is there somewhere I can learn what permissions this needs?